# How do I set inline-size in an svg that contains text?

Tags: css, google-chrome, svg, firefox, styling

The SVG 2.0 specification [states](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/text.html#InlineSize) that the inline-size attribute can be used in text elements in order to have automatic text wrapping, here is an example code block of such an svg (taken from the above link):

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     width="300" height="100" viewBox="0 0 300 100">

  <text x="50" y="30" style="font: 20px sans-serif; inline-size: 200px">
    This text wraps at 200 pixels.
  </text>

</svg>
```

However it fails to render the text-wrapping effect on any browser I've tried.

I know that not all of the SVG 2.0 specification is yet implemented, but as this attribute is CSS styling, browsers like Mozilla Firefox should have this implemented, as stated [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/style) (where it says the style tag can be used to embed CSS styling) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inline-size) (where it says inline-size is a valid CSS style attribute).

I am, however, unable to recreate the example above. Is it simply the case that embedded styling in an SVG element does not yet support the inline-size attribute? If so I would appreciate a source in order to support this conclusion, since the Mozilla docs (shared above) explicitly claim full parity between the style tag in SVGs and HTML CSS styling.

Comment: No browser has implemented this.

Comment: Browsers don't support quite a lot of SVG 1.1 text capabilities - lack of support for SVG 2 text capabilities should be expected IMHO.